# Clear preferred activities for USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED intent

Tags: android, android-intent, usb, default, intentfilter

I want my app to be able to relinquish its preferred activity status for USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED.

If I declare an intent filter for some mime type as follows:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:scheme="content" />

    <data android:mimeType="audio/x-wav" />
</intent-filter>
```

I can call `PackageManager#getPreferredActivities(...)` and confirm that my activity has become the default for the given mime type. Subsequently calling `PackageManager#clearPackagePreferredActivities(getPackageName())` removes the default, as expected, and the user will be prompted to select an app when they try to open a file matching that mime type.

In the case of USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED, however, where the intent-filter is declared as follows,

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

nothing is listed when I call `PackageManager#getPreferredActivities(...)` despite the fact that my activity has become the default for the action (as can be confirmed in Applications > Default applications > Set as default. Likewise, calling clearPackagePreferredActivities() accomplishes nothing. Is it not possible to clear the default activity for USB_ACCCESSORY_ATTACHED? Thanks!